# MySQL ORDER BY performs better with a SUBQUERY than a PLAIN simple query

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, mysql-5.6

For some reason I don't understand this plain regular MySQL query runs SLOWER than expected. From what I understood, MySQL would first slice the queryset using WHERE then sort the subset of results. The impression I get is something different (?). Perhaps the output of the "optimized" query is NOT trustable to be accurate even though it's returning the same row. The same query without the ORDER BY clause runs really fast.

```
Server version:     5.6.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `core_tweet`
WHERE `core_tweet`.`streamer_id` = 44566
ORDER BY `platform_id`
LIMIT 1;
1 row in set (27.84 sec)
rerun with SQL_NO_CACHE (46.39 sec)
```

This is the now "optimized" query:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
  SELECT *
  FROM `core_tweet`
  WHERE `core_tweet`.`streamer_id` = 44566
) sub
ORDER BY sub.platform_id ASC
LIMIT 1;
1 row in set (0.56 sec)
rerun with SQL_NO_CACHE (3.82 sec)
```

And their respective EXPLAIN outputs:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                                       | key         | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | core_tweet | index | core_tweet_streamer_id_51082c18_fk_core_streamer_id | platform_id | 402     | NULL |  462 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------------+


+----+-------------+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys                                       | key                                                 | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL                                                | NULL                                                | NULL    | NULL  | 52072 | Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | core_tweet | ref  | core_tweet_streamer_id_51082c18_fk_core_streamer_id | core_tweet_streamer_id_51082c18_fk_core_streamer_id | 5       | const | 52072 | NULL           |
+----+-------------+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------+
```

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `core_tweet` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `published_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `platform_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `retweet_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `favorite_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hashtags` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tweet_url` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `streamer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `platform_id` (`platform_id`),
  KEY `core_tweet_streamer_id_51082c18_fk_core_streamer_id` (`streamer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `core_tweet_streamer_id_51082c18_fk_core_streamer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`streamer_id`) REFERENCES `core_streamer` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26267613 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Tables stats:

```
core_tweet row count: 25856893
core_tweet `WHERE streamer_id = 44566` row count: 25868
core_streamer row count: 47203
```

Comment: It's strage. Please benchmark the queries again using SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * ..
I guess the first query was cached, and this is why the second one was so fast.

Comment: adding SQL_NO_CACHE to both statements: 1 row in set (46.39 sec) vs 1 row in set (3.82 sec)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Create index by `(streamer_id, platform_id)`.

Comment: Exactly like Akina said, to include both where clause and sort column in an index.

Comment: It would be nice to understand what's happening, adding the index would solve it but my "optimized" query also solved id.

Comment: The first query could be very fast if the matching id (44566) is found somewhere near the top of the index. I guess that is why MySQL is preferring it.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but in reality optimisers are free to make their own internal "optimisations" so although the defined order of operations is `WHERE` before `ORDER BY`, that is not guaranteed. For whatever reason (probably poor cardinality estimates) your first query is first sorting first using the index on `platform_id` then applying the filter on `streamer_id`. Since MySQL uses [subquery materialisation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-materialization.html) the 2nd query forces the optimal (and correct) order of execution.

Comment: Could you do a `SELECT platform_id, streamer_id FROM t ORDER BY 1` and use any streamer_id from, e.g. top 100?

Comment: The only real reason I can see that this would happen though is stale statistics. Perhaps refreshing the statistics will help? [`ANALYZE TABLE core_tweet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html)

Comment: Using `SELECT MIN()` rather than ORDER BY also worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

This may allow even the first version to run faster yet:

Replace `KEY(streamer_id)` with

```
INDEX(streamer_id, platform_id)
```